# Когда следует использовать img с атрибутами srcset/sizes, а когда - picture с source и почему?

Tags: html, изображения

На [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/) представлена замечательная [статья по адаптивным изображениям](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), где были рассмотрены два средства работы с адаптивными изображениями - атрибуты **srcset** и **sizes** а также тэги **picture** и **source**:

```html
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

Вот только чего я не понял, так это в каком случае какое средство использовать.
В первом случае (с **img**) у нас разница только в разрешениях, при этом изображено одно и то же (во всяком случае, мы это знаем, а браузер, выполняющий рендеринг, это проверять не собирается). А что если мы сделаем разные изображения? Скажем, для широких экранов - альбомную ориентацию, а для узких - портретную. Можно сказать: "**srcset** и **sizes** для этого не предназначены". Хорошо, а что технически пойдёт не так, если изображения отличаются не только расширением?

Тоже самое и с picture/source. В каждом тэге source у нас разные изображения, но что технически пойдёт не так, как эти изображения будут отличаться только разрешением?

В статье было сказано:

> Примечание: вам следует использовать атрибут `media` только при
> художественном оформлении; когда вы используете `media`, не применяйте
> медиа-условия с атрибутом `sizes`.

Это примечание лишь порождает новые вопросы:

1. Почему следует использовать атрибут `media` только при художественном оформлении? Причина-то какая?
2. Сказано использовать атрибут `media`, но не тэг `source`. То есть как бы если у нас не случай с художественным оформлением, то тэг `source` использовать можно, только без атрибута `media`?

Comment: [HTML picture or srcset for responsive images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31848856/2881286)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перечитайте внимательно статью, выписав для себя разницу между тэгом, атрибутом и "медиа-условием" (судя по вопросам, это не будет лишним).

Далее, методы, указанные в статье делятся по задачам:

1. обеспечить наилучшее отображение с точки зрения качества картинки (разрешение картинки) в зависимости от дисплея пользователя (обычный/retina, ПК/планшет/смартфон - у всех отличаются размеры экрана, пикселя, зернистость и др. характеристики.
2. Обеспечить наилучшее отображения с точки зрения дизайна/смысла - т.е. "художественное" оформление - зачем на смартфоне "большая" по количеству элементов картинка, если на маленьком экране будут чёткие,но мелкие детали... Можно выделить главный кусочек и отобразить его.

Кроме того, судя по статье и исходя из экспериментов, при использовании тэга `<img>` с атрибутом `srcset` и медиа-условиями браузер определяет возможности дисплея клиента, и исходя из этого подгружает одну(!) подходящую картинку... как бы вы не "играли" размерами окна в браузере, картинка будет с подходящим для вашего дисплея разрешением. В случае с тэгом `<picture>` будут подгружаться художественные варианты, в зависимости от размера окна браузера. Это существенные нюансы, которые отразятся на скорости загрузки страницы при объёмном "графическом" наполнении.

Также стоить обратить внимание, что тэг `<picture>` может использоватья без   вложенного тэга `<media>` - когда у нас одно и то же изображение, но мы хотим предложить разные его форматы.
И не рекомендуют при использовании тэга `media` внутри тэга `picture`,  добавлять медиа-условия в атрибут `sizes` тэга `img`. Видимо т.к. возникнет конфликт условий отображения, который разные браузеры будут решать по  разному... тут можно поэксперементировать, если интересно. Хотя два набора условий подряд для одного "художественного" изображения и так кажется "избыточным"...

Answer (score 3):

Вы никогда не должны использовать srcset для <img>, а всегда должны выбирать <picture>. Причин для этого несколько. Первая причина это то, что даже в сайте-примере, указанном в вышеупомянутой статье, по каким-то причинам эти srcset и источники работают неправильно, смотрите картинку ниже:
[image: демонстрация неработы srcset для img]

Несмотря на то, что наш медиазапрос подходит условию до 600px, браузер загружает вовсе не изображение elva-fairy-480w.jpg, как видно из вкладки Network
Вторая причина это несовершенство данного метода: он не позволяет указывать форматы исходных файлов, например добавить альтернативные источники изображения в форматах WEBP, AVIF, APNG и пр., в то время как <picture> является совершенным инструментом, позволяющим сочетать как медиазапросы, так и форматы исходных файлов. Синтаксис и логика его работы значительно понятнее, поддержка браузерами более чем достаточная - 97%.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Я приношу свои глубокие извенения за то, что не могу дать репутационный приз двум участникам несмотря на то, что оба ответа включая Ваш очень качественные. Особенно мне понравилось, что Вы сразу начали с рекомендации, а потом привели качественное объяснение с картинкой и экспериментальными данными. Мне очень жаль, что я вынужден ограничиться письменной благодарностью...

Comment: Не беспокойтесь, мы тут в первую очередь для того, чтобы помогать друг другу и развивать образование в русскоязычной среде пользователей. Как говорится: ученье - свет!

Answer (score 0):

В дополнении к предыдущим ответам, хочу дабавить важную деталь, о которой не упоминалось в том числе в самой статье, однако для ясности следовало бы,- атрибут srcset внутри тэга source также поддерживает ту самую ретину, на которой был сделан акцент при рассмотрении первого варианта. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg, elva-fairy-640w.jpg 2x">
  <img src="elva-fairy-640w.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```